# Property 'uid' does not exist on type '{ uid: string; token: DecodedIdToken; } | undefined'

Tags: typescript, firebase

I am getting the following error in vscode :

`Property 'uid' does not exist on type '{ uid: string; token: DecodedIdToken; } | undefined'.`

with the following code :

```
export const getUid = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let { auth: {uid} } = context;
});
```

I don't understand how `uid` could appear as "not defined" for a type defined as `{uid: string; .....}`.

(Note that `functions.https.onCall` is from the `firebase` package.)

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think this is vscode trying to tell you that context can be undefined

Comment: According to your error message the type also could be undefined. That's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be sure about that, but apparently firebase defines `functions.https.onCall` like so:

```
function onCall(
  data: Whatever,
  context: { auth?: { uid: string, /* ... */ } }
): void;
```

So `auth` could theoretically be undefined. I would suppose, it is so if user is not logged in, but it's only an assumption, i don't know how firebase works. You either have to check if it's not undefined explicitly

```
if(!context.auth) return;
let { auth: { uid } } = context;
```

Or tell the compiler you are sure it's defined (if you are really sure, otherwise it will be a runtime exception):

```
let { uid } = context.auth!;
```